# GMAIL API history endpoint returns a 404 not found response code only on Android

Tags: android, gmail-api

I'm trying to make a GMAIL API call to the history endpoint using a historyId. This call works on Postman and I receive a json response as I should. But when I'm trying to implement the same in Android Studio, it returns a 404 Not Found Error. Can anyone help me with this?

```
URL urlHist = new URL("https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/history?startHistoryId="+historyId);
            HttpURLConnection connHist = (HttpURLConnection) urlHist.openConnection();
            connHist.setRequestProperty("Authorization",token);
            connHist.setRequestMethod("GET");
            connHist.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
            connHist.setRequestProperty("Accept","application/json");
            connHist.setDoOutput(true);
            connHist.setDoInput(true);

            DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(connHist.getOutputStream());
            os.flush();
            os.close();
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use the Gmail API to build your requests. [Here](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/java) you can find an example on how to get started in Java. Your request should translate in something like this:

```
private static final String APPLICATION_NAME = "Your Android APP name";
private static final JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();

//...

final NetHttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
Gmail service = new Gmail.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, getCredentials(HTTP_TRANSPORT))
                .setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME)
                .build();

ListHistoryResponse history = service.users().history().list("me").setStartHistoryId(historyId).execute();
```